# Xmpp openfire connect to client(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ssl, xmppframework

I am developing chat application for iOS. We have configured Openfire (VPN) server with some IP Address. How can I connect with this IP from my iOS app using Robbiehanson's XMPPFramework. We did not register any domain. In Openfire admin page the server name is "localhost"

I have followed the following steps to connect.

1. I had mentioned IPaddress as:

   ```
       [xmppStream setHostName:@"my server ip"];
       [xmppStream setHostPort:5222];
   ```
2. And mentioned some user name like:

   ```
     NSString  *myJID = @"testuser@localhost";
     NSString  *myPassword = @"sample";
   ```

When I run the app The below delegate method got called.

```
-(void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketDidConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket   *)socket
```

But below method not get called

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender.
```

What is the reason it not get called. I had registered delegates in AppDelegate class.

```
[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Still not get called. I got the following in Xcode console.

```
<<stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='localhost'>>
```

- What is the issue? How can I test with this one locally? How can I
  configure this one registered domain?
- Do we need SSL Certificate for registered domain with
  Openfire? Whether it is must or optional?

Comment: have you successfully integrate openfire with xmpp?